# xdg-mime returns "xprop: unable to open display '' "

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, mime-type

I'm attempting to track down a problem with a particular CSS file being returned as text/html instead of text/css.

file -mime install.css returns some less useful info:

```
install.css: text/x-c; charset=us-ascii
```

So I was encouraged to use xdg-mime instead:

```
[box]# xdg-mime query filetype install.css
xprop:  unable to open display ''
usage:  xprop [-options ...] [[format [dformat]] atom] ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was logged in over ssh.   Logging in via noMachine and issuing the command on a terminal in that session worked.  No idea why it fails over ssh.

Comment: Try to login with `ssh -X` if you have an X Server installed on your remote machine. This will forward the `DISPLAY` to your local machine.